# JavaScript creating new line in HTML, onclick pastes values underneath one another

Tags: javascript, html

So i've looked around the website a lot but can't seem to find the most *basic* way to create a new line in HTML through JavaScript. This would be activated by an onclick button that would copy the results from a table and post them in a separate div. Ideally, the "add line" button wouldn't be replicated with each new line that was created. Rather, i'd have one button that each time was pressed, would take values from a table and make a text with all the values appear (not in another table). This concatenation of values wouldn't be replaced once the new values are copied; the new values would be pasted underneath.

This is what i've been experimenting with:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row4">
        <td>
            Result:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="00" name="row4" class="row" id="row3_1"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="00" name="row4" class="row" id="row3_2"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="00" name="row4" class="row" id="row3_3"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="00" name="row4" class="row" id="row3_4"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="postToClipboard" onclick="postToClipboard()" value="Post results!">
<div id="clipboard"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function postToClipboard() {
    document.getElementById("clipboard").innerHTML = '<p>' + "Final Time =  " + (arrayRow3[0]  || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[1] || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[2] || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[3] || 00) + '</p>';
}
```

I learnt about join() recently but i'll implement it in my next project instead.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Better if you could create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Would be easy to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript, use `+=` to append, rather than `=` to overwrite:

```
function postToClipboard() {
    document.getElementById("clipboard").innerHTML += '<p>' + "Final Time =  " + (arrayRow3[0]  || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[1] || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[2] || 00) + ":" + (arrayRow3[3] || 00) + '</p>';
}
```

Comment: I love you stranger. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question Kenney if thats ok: how would you go about making a button that deletes any text that the first button puts up? (deletes the last line first)

Comment: Officially you should ask another question, but unofficially (I shouldn't be doing this but...), you could clear the #clipboard by assigning `""` to it's innerHTML. If you want to clear only the last line on each button click, look into the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) and [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Kenney. I'll name my program after you!